# How to cancel ScheduledExecutorService/ Runnable to stop loading the InterstitialAd on backpress/exit the activity

Tags: java, android, admob

I want to display  InterstitialAd only once at a particuar time.But before executing the InterstitialAd load method if the user back press the activity and exit the activity the ScheduledExecutorService or Runnable method should stop completely, but it is running in the background and displays the InterstitialAd at particular time . How to Stop to display the InterstitialAd in the following code.Thank you.

```
public class CustomActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        prepareAd();

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
                Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Log.i("hello", "world");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                            mInterstitialAd.show();
                        } else {
                           Log.d("TAG"," Interstitial not loaded");
                        }



                    }
                });

            }
        }, 30, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

     }


    public void  prepareAd(){

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }

 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is method on activity, `isFinishing()`, which determines if activity is still running or has been destroyed or called `finish()` on from.

If it returns true, you can show ad, If false, cancel the scheduler.

Example

```
           public void run() {

                    if (!isFinishing() && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {

                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    } else if(isFinishing()){

                        scheduler.shutdown();
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.d("TAG"," Interstitial not loaded");   
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Thank you Sir it worked ,your Saved my day.@Touhidul Islam

Comment: @KatrinaPathak Please accept the answer as it has solved the problem :)